# Ruby TCPSocket request not getting response

Tags: ruby, sockets, tcpsocket

I have been reading up on TCPSockets over at [TutorialsPoint](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/ruby/ruby_socket_programming.htm) and I need a simple client to make requests but I do not confused why there is no response.

**Website API Login**

> The
>   login command accepts a JSON object as argument followed by the EOT character for a response.

From the website's API

This is what I have

```
def connect
    url = "someurl.com"
    port = 19534 
    loginRequest = 'login {"protocol":1,"client":"testruby","clientver":0.1}' +"\04"

    s = TCPSocket.open(url,port)

    s.puts(loginRequest)
    while line = s.gets
        puts line.chop
    end
puts "end"
s.close
end
connect
```

**My attempts**

1) I run the ruby code in terminal but my connection to the server is immediately closed.

I'm totally clueless and would appreciate some directions on this.

Comment: Is there a running server on the domain and port that you are specifying?

Comment: The port specified is 19534 according to https://vndb.org/d11 and yes the server is running on the domain.

Comment: It's located in the link as above  vndb.org/d11

Comment: they are optional as specified by the docs

Comment: try socket read instead of socket gets , like this:

socket = TCPSocket.open(host,port)  #

socket.print(request)   

response = socket.read

Comment: I suppose you have added require 'socket' at the top, haven't you? and have you tried socket.read instead of socket.gets?

Answer (score 2):

It seems that the server is using raw TCP/IP, using the 0x04 character to signify an "End of Message".

Your code seems to prefer blocking IO (although it probably wouldn't be my first choice), so allow me to suggest a blocking API adjustment:

```
require 'socket'

module VNDB
   public

   def send_message message
      raise "Not connected" unless @s
      @s.write (message + "\x04")
   end

   def get_message
      raise "Not connected" unless @s
      message = ''
      message << @s.getc until message[-1] == "\x04"
      message
   end

   def connect
       url = "someurl.com"
       port = 19534 
       loginRequest = 'login {"protocol":1,"client":"testruby","clientver":0.1}' +"\04"

       @s = TCPSocket.open(url,port)

       send_message loginRequest
       puts get_message
       puts "end"
       @s.close
       @s = nil
   end
   extend self
end

VNDB.connect
```

P.S.

1. I couldn't test the code, because "someurl.com" isn't really the address, I guess.
2. The database server is NOT using Websockets (which is a name of a protocol), so please consider editing your question and removing that tag.